# kubernetes pod for celery

Tags: rabbitmq, kubernetes, celery

I need to run distributed task mechanism with Celery, RabbitMQ and Flower.

Usually people create a separate pod for each service which makes 3 pods in my case. My question is why making 3 pods?

I can create one pod with 3 containers. The services are tightly coupled, they should be all running to have a working solution.

What are the advantages to have 3 pods for 3 services instead of one pod with 3 containers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is application design decision.

The advantage with creating three pods, it gives the flexibility to scale the individual container.

eg.
you can run 3 Celery container and send traffic to one RabbitMQ.